# about 24 hours and 12 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change my hours into 12hrs not 24hrs.

this is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var newDate = new Date();
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
    $('#Date').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + " " + newDate.getDate() + ' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
    setInterval(function() {
        var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        $("#sec").html((seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds);
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
        var minutes = new Date().getMinutes();
        $("#min").html((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
    }, 1000);
    setInterval(function() {
        var hours = new Date().getHours();
        $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: @user it's unfortunate that you have used a bad tone in your question. The post sounds more like a demand than request. Also mentioning what you have tried would work in your favor.

Comment: what have you tried? did you try to find an answer on yor own before asking a question that has been  answered here a dozen of times?

Comment: sorry mr dropout, if i ddnt notice the other issue same to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this

```
newHours = (oldHours) % 12
if (newHours == 0) {
    newHours = 12;
}
```